# URL rewriting after a redirection

Tags: redirection

I have a Drupal website hosted in the server of our company. One partner has a domain name and we want to use this domain instead of the company's (sub-)domain for the Drupal website. He arrived to do the redirection, i.e. when we hit the partner domain the Drupal website appears. However, all the links inside the Drupal website still refer to the old actual company's domain and if we click them, the corresponding page loads but the URL doesn't change. If we try to write the URL manually in the browser, e.g. partner_domain.com/?q=about, we return to homepage however the domain doesn't change (my_friend_domain.com/?q=about); and then the same problem, wherever we click the page shows but the URL doesn't change.

I Googled it but no success. I tried [Domain 301 Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_301_redirect) module but it is not making any difference.

Comment: It sounds like the your install might have manually set the $base_url in your **settings.php**?

Comment: I've just checked the file, $base_url is commented, so unchanged.